# How to add button with events on third party windows form application?

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, gdi+, win32gui

I need to add one button with events on third party windows application, whose click event will open web browser with provided link.

Is there any way to achieve this using c#, .net framework?

I do have API(DLL) to access some of the events and can deploy with third party application. But it doesn't provide method to acces the winform controls. The DLL is a SDK to subscribe events and perform background operations on the third party app.

Is there any way to dynamically draw a button control on current active windows form?

Comment: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible since third party app, best approach would be to encapsulate the windows app with your own native app either by consuming the third party component as a control then adding your own buttons around the view that consumes it.

Comment: I do have API(DLL) to access some of the events and can deploy with third party application. But it doesn't provide method to acces the winform controls. The DLL is a SDK to subscribe events and perform background operations on the third party app.

Comment: That sounds standard to not allow access to the control and only allow method calls from the interface and ability to subscribe to certain events, really your only two options are to request the third party to add a button and expose the event so you can trigger logic to open web link or piggy back off an existing event you can subscribe to.